# How does Reshape() function works in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone explain what this line is doing in python code ?

`X.reshape((X.shape[0], 1) + X.shape[1:])`

I am using numpy here.

Comment: Why not try it out in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: With that downvote, I will remember it for next time.

Comment: I'm not the one that downvoted, but it's still a valid question. One of the great things about Python is that we can test things interactively.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this code is changing the shape of `X` to have an additional (size 1, or `singleton` if you are used to `MATLAB`) dimension.  So if the shape was previously `(3,3,3)` it changes it to `(3,1,3,3)`. This doesn't add any data since `3x3x3=3x1x3x3=27` It would probably be used so that the number of dimensions match (for functions that include another array).  An equivalent form would be:

```
X = X[:, None, ...]
```

For more about *why* you might want to do this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

Comment: I would rather call it `singleton` dim, borrowed from MATLAB.

Comment: Empty would be something like `np.random.rand(3,0,2)`, etc., i.e. a dim of length `0` AFAI understand dims. Also, that `singleton` term used by one more author here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3551859/3293881

Comment: Seems like the `numpy` docs mostly call it a "size 1 dimension"

Comment: There should be no spaces between the dots of the ellipsis (`...`) otherwise you may get a syntax error.

Comment: @kazemakase That's true [only as of Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax).