# Numpy array indexing: difference between [:, 0], [:, 0:1] and [:, [0]]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Consider a Numpy array

```
x = array(
  [[4, 0, 3, 3],
   [7, 9, 3, 5],
   [2, 4, 7, 6],
   [8, 8, 1, 6]])
```

Consider these 3 commands

```
x[: , 0]
x[: , 0:1]
x[: , [0]]
```

The first one yields `array([4, 7, 2, 8])`, while the second and third return

```
array(
  [[4],
   [7],
   [2],
   [8]])
```

> What explains this difference in behaviour ?

Comment: @Divakar How is my question a duplicate of the one you mentioned ?

Comment: Well basically the answer is with `x[: , 0]` dims are not preserved as there is dim reduction, while for other two cases, it is. It's somewhat discussed in [`this answer post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183182/) to the linked question.

Comment: @Divakar that question isn't of any help to me. You should read posts more carefully before you press the close button and not make abusive use of your gold badge... I don't have enough rep to warrant a reopen vote.

Comment: Maybe its a good time to start reading the [`docs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: @Divakar I've asked this question specifically because I don't have time to sift through the documentation. Is your close vote **upon duplicate reason** actually a rephrasing of RTFM ?

Comment: Well here you go, linked all questions that should solve your question. Just trying to keep the site clean. If those linked questions don't answer your question, please do explain why they don't. Appreciate your cooperation!

Comment: Indexing with `0` (scalar) selects a column returning a 1d.  `0:1` (slice) returns a 2d `view`.  `[0]` (list) returns a 2d copy.  That's a 'what happens?' answer.  A 'why?' could get into development history, or into compiled code?  Are you looking for something simple, or a deep explanation?

Comment: @hpaulj a simple explanation without technicalities. The elements you have provided are enlightening, thank you. If you reopened the question and posted this as an answer, I would accept it.