# Slicing a numpy array vs selecting a single element

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
```

If I slice the array `arr[:, :1]` my result is `array([[1], 
[4], [7]])`.

If I slice the array `arr[:, 0]` my result is `array([1, 4, 7])`.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the first case `arr[:, 1]` (?) I obtain `array([2, 5, 8])` which there is not a difference.

Comment: RelatedSO, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3551242/901925

Answer (score 4):

`:1` is a slice (which happens to be of length 1) so numpy returns a list for every line (first dim) in your array. This is why you have a 2-dimensional array as a result: you asked for a sub array with `:`.

`0` on the other hand is an index so numpy shrinks the result by 1 dimension resulting of a list of values (array of dimension 1 more precisely).

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing

claims that single element indexing behaves like the usual Python list indexing.  Slicing also follows this pattern

```
In [175]: arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [176]: arr
Out[176]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

single element indexing - returns a 1d array

```
In [177]: arr[1,:]
Out[177]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

slice indexing returns a 2d array

```
In [178]: arr[:1,:]
Out[178]: array([[0, 1, 2]])
```

with an equivalent list

```
In [179]: alist = arr.tolist()
```

single element indexing returns a list:

```
In [180]: alist[1]
Out[180]: [3, 4, 5]
```

slice indexing returns a nested list:

```
In [181]: alist[:1]
Out[181]: [[0, 1, 2]]
```

Same pattern holds when I index a 1d array, or list of numbers.

`numpy` generalizes this to columns, and higher dimensions, but tries to keep the pattern the same.

```
In [187]: arr[:,0]
Out[187]: array([0, 3])
In [188]: arr[:,:1]
Out[188]: 
array([[0],
       [3]])
In [189]: [x[0] for x in alist]
Out[189]: [0, 3]
In [190]: [x[:1] for x in alist]
Out[190]: [[0], [3]]
```