# Tensorflow: How to slice tensor with number of dimension not changed?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For example, if we have:

```
a = tf.constant(np.eye(5))
a
<tf.Tensor 'Const:0' shape=(5, 5) dtype=float64>
a[0,:]
<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float64>
```

The slice of tensor `a` will reduce the original number of dimension `2` to `1`

How could I just directly get the sliced with rank not changed like:?

```
a[0,:]
<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=(1,5) dtype=float64>
```

(`tf.expand_dims(a[0,:], axis=0)` could work, but are there more direct and easy way?)

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two direct ways, quite similar to those available in NumPy ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3551242/1233251)).

1. Fetch a range on that axis of size 1: `a[x:x+1]`
2. Add an axis with `None`: `a[None, x]`

```py
a[0:1]
```

```
<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice_1:0' shape=(1, 5) dtype=float64>
```

Some actual tensor running shows the expected outcome.

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(a[0])
    sess.run(a[0:1])
    sess.run(a[None, 0])
```

```
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```