# Iterate numpy array and keep dimensions

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I would like to iterate through a 2D numpy array (especially using nditer) and keep the number of dimensions of the iterated array. In doing this I would like to avoid any operation on the iterated elements. The solution should be set only once either on the iterated array or the iterator.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(5, 2)

for row in X:
    print(row.shape)

>>> (2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
(2,)
```

However I would like to have:

```
>> (1, 2)
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
```

I would like to find a solution that can be applied only once and not for each row like `row = row.reshape(1,-1)`.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use nditer? This question could provide a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551242/numpy-index-slice-without-losing-dimension-information

Answer (score 2):

Iterating on an array is like iterating on a list of lists - it returns the elements as indexed on the first dimension:

```
In [48]: X = np.random.randn(5, 2)                                           
In [49]: X[0,:]                                                              
Out[49]: array([0.59964924, 0.46057338])
In [50]: for row in X:print(row)                                             
[0.59964924 0.46057338]
[1.09308258 0.06495922]
[ 0.98928476 -1.07894574]
[-1.31303644 -0.34589506]
[0.31475676 0.3003112 ]
```

You could iterate on indices, and use a list index:

```
In [51]: for i in range(X.shape[0]): print(X[[i],:])                         
[[0.59964924 0.46057338]]
[[1.09308258 0.06495922]]
[[ 0.98928476 -1.07894574]]
[[-1.31303644 -0.34589506]]
[[0.31475676 0.3003112 ]]
```

`X[[1]]`, `X[1:2]`, `X[1][None,:]`, `X[None,1]` all do the same.

I don't think there's a way of incorporating those directly into a

```
for ... in X:
```

expression.

`nditer` can be awkward to use. Normally it iterates at the element level, not at the 'row' level, giving us a 0d array.  And it isn't any faster than a `for` iteration.  So I don't think it's useful here.

====

The suggest link, [Numpy index slice without losing dimension information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551242/numpy-index-slice-without-losing-dimension-information), inspired me to try:

```
In [57]: for row in X[:,None]: print(row)                                    
[[0.59964924 0.46057338]]
[[1.09308258 0.06495922]]
[[ 0.98928476 -1.07894574]]
[[-1.31303644 -0.34589506]]
[[0.31475676 0.3003112 ]]
```

In effect I'm turning `X` into a (5,1,2) array, so iteration on the first dimension produces (1,2) elements.  Instead of preserving a dimension, I'm adding one.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj ! `for row in X[:,None]: print(row)` is exactly what I was looking for. I tried some alternatives like `X[:, :, np.newaxis]` but I was getting the wrong shape i.e. (2,1) instead of (1,2).