# Keep Numpy Arrays 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm doing a lot of vector algebra and want to use numpy arrays to remove any need for loops and run faster.

What I've found is that if I have a matrix A of size [N,P] I constantly need to use `np.array([A[:,0]).T` to force `A[:,0]` to be a column vector of size (N,1)

Is there a way to keep the single row or column of a 2D array as a 2D array because it makes the following arithmetic sooo much easier. For example, I often have to multiply a column vector (from a matrix) with a row vector (also created from a matrix) to create a new matrix: eg

```
C = A[:,i] * B[j,:]
```

it'd be be great if I didn't have to keep using:

```
C = np.array([A[:,i]]).T * np.array([B[j,:]])
```

It really obfuscates the code - in MATLAB it'd simply be `C = A[:,i] * B[j,:]` which is easier to read and compare with the underlying mathematics, especially if there's a lot of terms like this in the same line, but unfortunately most of my colleagues don't have MATLAB licenses.

Note this isn't the only use case, so a specific function for this column x row operation isn't too helpful

Comment: Have you considered using Octave?

Comment: Just in general my organisation uses Python quite heavily so it's best if I can stick to Python

Comment: Also, a minimal reproducable example will include many individual instances where Python changes a matrix to a 1D array

Comment: You are misusing the term `matrix`. A 2-D `array` is not a `matrix` in `numpy`. It's an `array` and remains an `array` when slices are selected. Your question seems to be: *Can I use MATLAB syntax with numpy?* The answer is: No, you can't, you actually have to learn `numpy` to use `numpy`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using matrix in the mathematical sense, where a 2D array is a matrix. The question is, can I use less clunky numpy syntax in numpy? And MATLAB is a nice example of less clunky syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy index slice without losing dimension information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551242/numpy-index-slice-without-losing-dimension-information)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the dimension in the following way (using @ for matrix multiplication)

```
C = A[:,[i]] @ B[[j],:]
```

Notice the brackets around `i` and `j`, otherwise C won't be a 2-dimensional matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Even MATLAB/Octave squeezes out excess dimensions:

```
>> ones(2,3,4)(:,:,1)
ans = 
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
>> size(ones(2,3,4)(1,:))       # some indexing "flattens" outer dims
ans =
    1   12
```

When I started MATLAB v3.5 2d matrix was all it had; cells, struct and higher dimensions were later additions (as demonstrated by the above examples).

Your:

```
In [760]: A=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)  
In [762]: np.array([A[:,0]]).T
Out[762]: 
array([[0],
       [3]])
```

is more convoluted than needed.  It makes a list, then a (1,N) array from that, and finally a (N,1)

`A[:,[0]]`, `A[:,:,None]`, `A[:,0:1]` are more direct. Even `A[:,0].reshape(-1,1)`

I can't think of something simple that treats a scalar and list index the same.

Functions like `np.atleast_2d` can conditionally add a new dimension, but it will be a leading (outer) one.  But by the rules of `broadcasting` leading dimensions are usually 'automatic'.

### basic v advanced indexing

In the underlying Python, scalars can't be indexed, and lists can only be indexed with scalars and slices.  The underlying syntax allows indexing with tuples, but lists reject those.  It's `numpy` that has extended the indexing considerably - not with syntax but with how it handles those tuples.

`numpy` indexing with slices and scalars is `basic` indexing.  That's where the dimension loss can occur.  That's consistent with list indexing

```
In [768]: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]][1]
Out[768]: [4, 5, 6]
In [769]: np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])[1]
Out[769]: array([4, 5, 6])
```

Indexing with lists and arrays is `advanced` indexing, without any list counterparts.  This is perhaps where the differences between MATLAB and `numpy` are ugliest :)

```
 >> A([1,2],[1,2])
```

produces a (2,2) block.  In numpy that produces a "diagonal"

```
In [781]: A[[0,1],[0,1]]
Out[781]: array([0, 4])
```

To get the block we have to use lists (or arrays) that "broadcast" against each other:

```
In [782]: A[[[0],[1]],[0,1]]      
Out[782]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

To get the "diagonal" in MATLAB we have to use `sub2ind([2,2],[1,2],[1,2])` to get the [1,4] flat indices.

### What kind of multiplication?

In

```
np.array([A[:,i]]).T * np.array([B[j,:]])
```

is this elementwise (`.*`) or matrix?

For a (N,1) and (1,M) pair, `A*B` and `A@B` produce the same (N,M) result, but one uses `broadcasting` to generalize the `outer` product, and the other is inner/matrix product (with sum-of-products).

Answer (score 0):

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

> Returns a matrix from an array-like object, or from a string of data. A matrix is a specialized 2-D array **that retains its 2-D nature through operations**. It has certain special operators, such as * (matrix multiplication) and ** (matrix power).

I'm not sure how to re-implement it though, it's an interesting exercise.

As mentionned, matrix will be deprecated. But from np.array, you can specify the dimension with the argument ndim=2:

```
np.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)
```

Comment: Did you read the note? Using `np.matrix` is no longer recommended.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Had to read twice and scroll down and read it twice again to see it, sorry!

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I edited my answer to add an alternative with np.array

Comment: `np.matrix` was intended for wayward MATLAB users, - such as this.  The OP has a limited understanding of the differences.

Comment: Indeed, I'd love something that was MATLAB like where all data is treated the same

In Python it seems a = 12 and a = [12] are entirely different beasts even though the underlying data is the same so any function you wish to carry out on them is entirely unambiguous eg find the length or test if it's greater than 3 - in Python you have to use different functions... I run into this all the time and write lots of awkward code rather than Python being able to handle it in a MATLAB-like way

What if i and j are vectors (of the same size), will C = A[:, [i]] * B[[j],:] work? Who knows...

Answer (score 0):

I like joostblack's answer from a readability standpoint. However from a speed standpoint, [numpy's new axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) is quite a bit faster, which might make a difference depending on use case.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
B = A.T
A[np.newaxis, 0, :] @ B[:,np.newaxis, 1]
```

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]); b=a.T" "a[np.newaxis, 0, :] @ b[:, np.newaxis, 1]"
```

`100000 loops, best of 5: 2.09 usec per loop`

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]); b=a.T" "a[[0], :] @ b[:, [1]]"
```

`50000 loops, best of 5: 5.97 usec per loop`

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to do exactly what you want:

```
 np.outer(A[:,i], B[j,:])
```